# how can i correct this code while making it simpler

Tags: swift, string, variables, if-statement, int

I was just testing some code in Xcode's playground and I'm trying to learn how to use if-statements. Also how can I correct this code? I get a couple of errors when compiling it. One of them is "Cannot assign to value: '&&' returns immutable value". Is it possible to make the code more readable and simpler in the same time making it correct?

**The code that i wrote:**

```
var minutes = 10

var name = "Marcus"

var hours = 2

var status : String = " "

if minutes = nil && hours = !nil {

    status = "\(name) spent \(hours) hrs online"

} else if minutes = !nil && hours = nil {

    status = "\(name) spent \(minutes) mins online"

} else if minutes = !nil && hours = !nil {

    status = "\(name) spent \(hours) hrs & \(minutes) mins online"

}

print(status)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define `hours` and `minutes` like that, they will never be nil so no need to check. You have to declare them as optionals. And `switch` offers a clean solution to what your want:

```
var hours: Int? = 2
var minutes : Int? = 10
var name = "Marcus"

var status = ""
switch (hours, minutes) {
case (nil, nil):
    status = "both hours and minutes cannot be nil"
case (_, nil):
    status = "\(name) spent \(hours!) hrs online"
case (nil, _):
    status = "\(name) spent \(minutes!) mins online"
default:
    status = "\(name) spent \(hours!) hrs & \(minutes!) mins online"
}

print(status)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `=` instead of `==` is causing some of the errors.

Not that testing for `nil` when the variables are not optionals also triggers warnings.

Here is some code that compiles where you can play around with the logic now:

```
var minutes: Int? = 10
var name: String? = "Marcus"
var hours: Int? = 2
var status : String = "Hello"

if minutes == nil && hours != nil {
    status = "\(name) spent \(hours) hrs online"
} else if minutes != nil && hours == nil {
    status = "\(name) spent \(minutes) mins online"
} else if minutes != nil && hours != nil {
    status = "\(name!) spent \(hours!) hrs & \(minutes!) mins online"
}

print(status)
```